# Visual Studio 2022: Unable to attach to a x86 process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Using VS 2022 i am not able to attach to a 32 bit process. A message appears "Unable to attach to process. Access is denied". For x64 processes this works fine.

"Just in time" debugging is also not working (for both x86 and x64). The JIT window does not show up. The app being debugged stops for some seconds without showing the JIT dialog and then runs further.

Using VS2019 the result is the opposite: I am able to attach to 32 bit process but not to 64bit process. And again "Just in time" debugging is not working as described above.

I have read many posts on the internet but I could not get an answer. I tested all this with a simple console application to avoid unnecessary dependencies.

The main drawback is that with VS2022 I cannot debug a 32bit process which is launched by a parent process. For this to work I need JIT (Debugger.Break) or "attach to process".

I am running VS 2022 as admin under Win10 x64.

Does anybody out there have similar problems?

Comment: You describe scenarios where VS needs to use the remote debugger to attach to the process.  Intrinsically harder with more security software layers to fight through.  So start trying to get ahead by disabling the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: No, it's not remote debugging. The scenarios which I am describing are for programs on my local machine.

Comment: The reason may be related that the Visual Studio 2022 program is an x64 program. Even if you compile the x86 version, you must use the x64 toolset